# Android Room generates DAO with error when method returns RxJava Completable

Tags: android-room

I have @Insert method in Dao interface like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insertOrUpdateAllMessages(vararg messages: QuestMessageDbModel): Completable
```

When I build my project I get error:

```
error: local variable questsModels is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
      __insertionAdapterOfQuestDbModel.insert(questsModels);
                                              ^
```

When I open generated QuestDao_Impl.java, I see there such code:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I tried to replace vararg argument with List, but got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280994/andoridx-room-rx-issue), enabling j[ava8 compatibility](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) fixes the problem.

Add this to your desired project module gradle file, inside the android closure:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```