# Andoridx Room rx issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx

I'm start to use latest `androidx.room` version that support `io.reactivex` return type.

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}
```

Simple dao class

```
@Dao
interface UserDao : BaseDao<UserTable> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertUser(user: UserTable):Maybe<Long>

    @Update
    fun updateUser(user:UserTable):Completable

    @Query("DELETE FROM $USER_TABLE")
    fun clear()
}
```

generates `UserDao_Impl.java` with error

> error: local variable user is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Highlighted field is in this method

```
  @Override
  public Maybe<Long> insertUser(UserTable user) {
    return Maybe.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
     @Override
     public Long call() throws Exception {
       __db.beginTransaction();
        try {
          long _result = 
           __insertionAdapterOfUserTable.insertAndReturnId(user);//error line
           __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
         return _result;
        } finally {
         __db.endTransaction();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It's true that `(UserTable user)` should be declared as final in java but it is generated class.
Does any one came across this?

Comment: __insertionAdapterOfUserTable is final?

Comment: @sasikumar Yes, all the local variables are final

Comment: make long _result as final

Comment: Try using a newer Java version. In these the compiler is able to use variables which are not changed as if these were `final`.

Comment: @tynn thank you i'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux machine and combining answers of user3021656 and tynn got success build with

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and setting Java version for Android Studio as

> java version "1.8.0_191"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)